# my way of solving the permutation question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can all the letters in the word TATTOO be arranged if the vowels must be together in the order AOO?

my work:

in the word TATTO there are 6 letters

so 6p6

=6!/(6-6)!
=6!/0!
=6!
=6x5x4x3x2x1=720

answer=720

Comment: This is far too high.  All you have to arrange are $T,T,T,AOO$.   where the last, $AOO$ must occur as that block.  Not very many ways to do that...

Comment: I see the following arrangements.  $TTTAOO,~ TTAOOT,~TAOOTT,~AOOTTT$.  I count four... and did so with my fingers without needing to resort to using my toes.  Am I missing any arrangements and misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : AOO are together so consider them together as a single letter, say $AOO=\lambda$ now you have to find ways to arrange $T,T,T, \lambda$

Formula

> Ways to arrange $n$ objects when $m$ are same. $$\frac{n!}{m!}$$

Comment: so is the answer 72

Comment: No. The answer should be 4

Answer (score 0):

If we force AOO to be together, we can simply replace them with a single letter, say X. Then there are only four possibilities, depending on the place of X among the Ts.

Answer (score 0):

That's a wrong way brother....Here's how to do it!
we've the word TATTOO and we've to arrange its letters in such a way that vowels are together in the order (AOO),so
we can rearrange the word for our convenience in the following manner,
(AOO)TTT. 
Now we can treat (AOO) as a single entity....say 'x'
So,we've (AOO)TTT = xTTT.
Now total no. of arrangements can be calculated using the formula for 'Total no of arrangements of n objects having 'p' objects of one kind, 'q' objects of second kind and 'r' objects of third kind i.e.,

P = n!/p!.q!.r!
So in the above case,

P = 4!/3! = 4.3!/3! = 4
Hence, total number of arrangements are "4"...Hope this helped!

Comment: thank you i undertsand it now,i also needed help on thisother questin it wouldnt let me post ,i would appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: heres the question: Four boys and four girls try out for a school musical. The number of ways that the director can select a male lead singer, a female lead singer, and 3 students to provide vocal back-ups is